# Point of Sale app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, development-environment

This is a very general question....

I'm pretty new to the development world - mostly doing UI/UX and figuring it out as I go.  I'm confident with HTML,CSS,JQ and need to work on my javascript.

Someone asked me if I could develop a Point of Sale app.  I don't know what the customers needs are yet. First I need to find out this is something within realm of possibilities in my current skill set.

What do I need to no about making a point of sale app? What questions should I ask? I imagine there is a lot of security functionality, right?  What scripting languages are involved?

In info that can help me get started is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately if you're asking this question you're not going to be able to build this application. If you told the customer you would be able to, you would be misleading them.

If you want to be able to take this kind of work in the future, I would recommend building out a few applications on your own with different stacks. If you find one that you like and is easy for you to work with, build a complex application on your own (this way you have nobody dependent on you as you learn). You'll know when you're at a point where you can take a contracting gig, and you'll have a portfolio to show your potential customers what you can do.

There's a lot that goes into an application outside of the front-end. Just having HTML, CSS, and jQuery experience just won't be enough.

Comment: Good advice, thank you!  What do you mean by "different stacks", and finding an easy one?  I'm doing front-end stuff at work and everything is hosted like a website.  Would it be safe to assume all web based apps have a similar structure? That being said, a point of sale application should be web based right? not local like an exe?

Comment: Well some stacks are easier for others. For instance, you might want to try a full-stack javascript application to start, since you have some exposure to javascript. Two off of the top of my head that I can think of is MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node) and MeteorJS. These stacks will let you write both your front-end and server logic in one language (Javascript) so the learning curve isn't as steep.

I can't comment on what kind of application they would want. These stacks will let you build web apps and native apps though

Comment: Check out Square. https://squareup.com/ It's a POS application that uses a native app. These applications can be pretty intense, or simple. It really just depends.

Comment: I've used squareup at a local business - it is good stuff!  To Andrew Osborn's point - its sounds like I need to familiarize myself with some back-end languages - or work with a back end programmer. I just found out the client wants to sell whatever I make - I'm thinking I'm going to have to let this job slide.  Its a bummer.  I could use a new bike, and desperately need to upgrade my monitors!!

Answer (score 0):

**What do I need to know about making a point of sale app?**

Personally i believe you should make a basic AS-IS POS application first, do some research gather data regarding some very basic modules of POS. Which can be lets say customers, items or services, vendors, Purchases and POS. Expenses can be added as well if required.

Focus a market you want to make it for can be restaurants, cafe etc.

Since you are a UX/UI designer try to make a web application arrange controls accordingly and keep it responsive enough to run on any device (PC, Tablets etc.) and keep it as user friendly as possible.

**What questions should I ask?**

Further show it and discuss with your customer about what further enhancement do they require.

**I imagine there is a lot of security functionality, right?**

Well it depends, i must say, just do the MATHS right that is more important.

**What scripting languages are involved?**

In General terms it completely depends on your choice. In technical terms i am familiar in making POS with ASP.NET using AngularJS and MSSQL as database server.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17515174)

Comment: @ImranAliKhan, he's not asking a new question, he's suggesting answers to the OP's questions. But the original is off topic anyway